# Tensorflow, Python: ImportError: undefined symbol: _PyUnicode_AsWideCharString

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I keep getting the following error, when using tensorflow in PyCharm:

```
/home/user/tensorflow/bin/python /home/user/PycharmProjects    /TensorPlay/hello.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/user/PycharmProjects/TensorPlay/hello.py", line 2, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "/home/user/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/home/user/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    import ctypes
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ctypes/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from _ctypes import Union, Structure, Array
ImportError: /home/user/tensorflow/lib/python3.5/lib-dynload/_ctypes.cpython-35m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so: undefined symbol: _PyUnicode_AsWideCharString

Process finished with exit code 1
```

hello.py is this simple example code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

node1 = tf.constant(3.0, tf.float32)
node2 = tf.constant(4.0)
print(node1, node2)
```

PyCharm detects all the Tensorflow elements and autocomplete everything i want to.

I also tried to run the virtualenv in the console. 
Any Python related leads to the same error. I tried to upgrade tensorflow with

```
source ~/tensorflow/bin/activate
pip3 install --upgrade tensorflow
```

and had the exact same error too (Just instead of hello.py there was an error in file pip3)

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
I guess I see the problem. Might it be that my virtualenv wants Python 3.5.3? I thing with the last upgrade my Linux upgraded to Python 3.5.4 How can I fix it without creating a new virtualenv? And how I can make sure it doesn't happen on future updates?

Comment: I would suggest using [anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/downloads) and use conda command to install tensorflow and then run your python tensorflow program.  Please read this [manual](https://thinkingvirtually.blogspot.in/2017/08/python-anaconda-navigator-explained.html) for more help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I could only fix the issue with deleting the old virtualenv and setting up a new one.

Comment: I, too, surpassed this by using a new env. But I still haven't figured out why this happens. Anyone found the cause yet?